# Is it possible to use "py" instead of "python" at the command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Do you think it's possible in Ubuntu instead of typing `python3 test.py` every time I want to run a script, to use a shorthand equivalent such like this: `py test.py`? In other words, what I want is to make a shorthand command for `python3` that should look like this: `py`. Can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure.  You can use the bash alias command to do something like this:

```
alias py=python3
```

Put it somewhere like `.bashrc` and IIRC it will be set up for each (interactive) session.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Note that `~/.bashrc` is bash's profile. If you're using other shells, e.g. `zsh`, you need put it into `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not ensure the top line of your python code has

```
#!/bin/python3
```

Then make sure the file is executable

```
chmod my_python_code.py +x
```

Now just run it

```
./my_python_code.py
```

The previous alias command will also work - even if you do the above steps.

```
./bye.py
```